# PLSQL to SQL - DatabaseLink Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

straight forward question, but interesting enought, I didn't find anything. Probably I'm searching for the wrong keywords:
We have 2 Databases, one Oracle, one SQL, connected via Links.

I'd like to check, if some data is in the Oracle-Part, but not in the SQL one.

Selecting it from the PLSQLDev is pretty straightforward:

> SELECT * from Core.Event@Link

But as soon as I try to select specific fields like :

> SELECT Id from Core.Event@Link

It tells me the qualifier is invalid.
I tried all shennanigans like alias select:

> SELECT ie.Id from Core.Event@Link ie

But it keeps telling me the qualifier is invalid.
Is there a special syntax I have to keep in mind?

Thanks in advance and a good weekend.

Matthias

Comment: Did you try enclosing them Quotes and checking if your sql-server implementation is case sensitive.

Comment: I checked for case Sensivity and tried everything with the column names. If I add the column names in quotes, I get:
"Preceding line from Link"